# i18n geo usage with next-i18next & Next's built in internationalized routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to follow [the example within the i18n folder](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/i18n) but am running into some issues.

How our use case differs from the example in the following ways:

- We still want to use next-i18next and store our translations in JSON files.
- We want to use different paths for different locales like the behavior is when using Next's built-in Internationalized Routing, i.e. when user is visiting from Iceland, we want to have all of his visiting pathnames prefixed with /is.

Here's the code for the middleware I'm currently working with:

```ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;
const SUPPORTED_LOCALES = ["en", "is", "pt"];
const DEFAULT_LOCALE = "en";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const currentPathName = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  // 1. Only rewrite files that don't have a file extension (favicon, etc)
  // 2. We don't want to detect locale if the user is already visiting with a locale prefix.
  if (!PUBLIC_FILE.test(currentPathName)) {
    let country = req.geo?.country?.toLowerCase();

    // If we're in development we don't have req.geo data so we fallback to Icelandic
    if (!country && process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      country = "is";
    }

     // Determine if the user is visiting, already with a locale suffix
    const isVisitingWithLocalePath =
      !!SUPPORTED_LOCALES.find((l) => currentPathName.includes(l)) ||
      currentPathName === `/${country}`;

    const locale =
      req.headers.get("accept-language")?.split(",")?.[0] || DEFAULT_LOCALE;

    // Use the country but if it isn't available, use the browser locale
    const newLocale = country || locale;

    if (!isVisitingWithLocalePath) {
      req.nextUrl.locale = newLocale;
      req.nextUrl.pathname = `/${newLocale}`;
    } else {
      req.nextUrl.locale =
        currentPathName === `/${country}`
          ? DEFAULT_LOCALE
          : currentPathName.split("/")[1];
    }

    return NextResponse.rewrite(req.nextUrl).cookie("NEXT_LOCALE", newLocale);
  }
}
```

When visiting our page we receive the following error:

```ts
Error: The provided `as` value (/) is incompatible with the `href` value (/[company]).
```

If I add `console.log(req.nextUrl)` just before returning, this is the output (running locally) when visiting /:

```ts
NextURL {
  href: '/is/is',
  origin: '',
  protocol: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: '',
  hostname: '',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/is',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

Comment: Are you using this with Next.js i18n routing enabled as well?

Comment: Yes, that's what we wanted for better SEO - having each locale with its own pathname.

Comment: The next-i18next package already has support for localeS subpaths.

Comment: Yes, that's not my issue. I just need to redirect users to the correct subpath based on their geolocation - not their browser's locale settings.

Comment: If you're setting the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie, do you actually need to modify the `req.nextUrl.locale` and `req.nextUrl.pathname`? Wouldn't the cookie be enough for Next.js i18n routing to route to the correct path?